# Waterfall plot with emphasizing select points

Tags: r, bar-chart, waterfall

I would like to make a nice waterfall plot emphasizing select points -- in R you can generate a waterfall plot as follows:

Imagine a sequence of numbers from 2 to -2, as follows:

```
m = seq (from=2.0 ,to=-2.0,by= -0.05)
barplot(m)
```

This results in an array of 81 points

```
>m
#[1]  2.00  1.95  1.90  1.85  1.80  1.75  1.70  1.65  1.60  1.55  1.50  1.45
#[13]  1.40  1.35  1.30  1.25  1.20  1.15  1.10  1.05  1.00  0.95  0.90  0.85
#[25]  0.80  0.75  0.70  0.65  0.60  0.55  0.50  0.45  0.40  0.35  0.30  0.25
#[37]  0.20  0.15  0.10  0.05  0.00 -0.05 -0.10 -0.15 -0.20 -0.25 -0.30 -0.35
#[49] -0.40 -0.45 -0.50 -0.55 -0.60 -0.65 -0.70 -0.75 -0.80 -0.85 -0.90 -0.95
#[61] -1.00 -1.05 -1.10 -1.15 -1.20 -1.25 -1.30 -1.35 -1.40 -1.45 -1.50 -1.55
#[73] -1.60 -1.65 -1.70 -1.75 -1.80 -1.85 -1.90 -1.95 -2.00
```

What I would like to do is emphasize say points m[13] and m[37] by giving it a different color and potentially displaying the barplot in 3D.

Anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

I am using ggbio these days and believe there must be a way -- say with an S4 object to achieve the an object which then I could use with autoplot.

Anyone clever enough out there to have this figured out?

Comment: Do you mean to plot 3D barplot?

Comment: I like the `staircase.plot` from the `plotrix` package

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#data
m = seq (from=2.0 ,to=-2.0,by= -0.05)

#define colours for bars
mCol <- rep(1,length(m))

#emphasizing 2 points
mCol[c(13,37)] <- 2

#plot
barplot(m,col=mCol)
```

[image]

Comment: great Idea -- now can you think of how I could make this 3D with this point or points pulled out in the 3rd dimension?